# ERROR SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `favorites` () values ())

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel, api

I am trying to copy a station from the station repository and add it to my favorite repository. I am in a laravel rest API. Thanks for the help!

Here is my controller:

```
class FavoriteController extends Controller
{
    private $favoriteRepository;
    private $stationRepository;

public function __construct(FavoriteRepository $favoriteRepository, StationRepository $stationRepository)
{
    $this->favoriteRepository = $favoriteRepository;
    $this->stationRepository = $stationRepository;
}


public function store(int $station_id)
{
    $favorite = array();
    $favorite[] = $this->stationRepository->findByField("id", $station_id);
    $this->favoriteRepository->create($favorite);
    return response()->json($favorite, 201);
}
}
```

Here is the database for the favorites:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->foreign('city')->references('name')->on('cities');
        $table->integer('station_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('station_id')->references('id')->on('stations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        #$table->boolean('is_private');
    });
}
```

Here is my Favorite model

```
class Favorite extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['station_id', 'user_id', 'updated_at', 'name', 'city'];

public $timestamps = false; 
}
```

And I have both these methods in my repos:

```
function model()
{
    return "App\\Station";
}
```

Comment: I would recommend throwing a `dd($favorite);` on the line before you create. It looks to me as if that is empty.

Comment: Thanks @AlexHarris, found out that it was empty! I solved the problem by getting rid of the repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function store($station_id)
{
    $favorite = $this->stationRepository->where("id", $station_id)->first()->toArray();
    $this->favoriteRepository->create($favorite);
    return response()->json($favorite, 201);
}
}
```